# Submit a form and display the result in alertbox using opencart

Tags: php, jquery, opencart

I need to result in alert box in opencart. It means once I submit the data I need to display the result in alertbox

This is My view.tpl file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#submit').submit(function() { 
    $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'), 
        success: function(response) {
            $('#submit').html(response);
        }
    });
    return false; 
});
</script>

<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="your_name"><br>
<input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

This is my controller file

```
public function index() 
{ 
    $this->load->model('test/test');
    $this->data['action'] = $this->url->link('test/test');
    $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
    $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');     
    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('test/test', $data));  
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) )
    {
        $your_name = $_POST["your_name"];
        echo $your_name;
        $email =$_POST["email"];
        echo $email;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return as a JSON in your controller.

```
e.g return json_encode($var);
```

Something like this.

```
public function index() { 
    $this->load->model('test/test');
    $this->data['action'] = $this->url->link('test/test');
    $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
    $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('test/test', $data));  
    $result = [];
    if( isset($_POST['submit']) ){
        $your_name = $_POST["your_name"];
        $email =$_POST["email"];
        $result['yourname'] = $your_name;
        $result['email'] = $email;
    }
    return json_encode($result);
}
```

Then, `console.log(response);` in your js.

Comment: Thx for your suggestion but i didn't get any response in console.log

Comment: Where do you console it ?

Comment: console it into the view.tpl file